# How to catch edited message using telegraph

Tags: node.js, telegraf

I need to catch edited messages. I tried like:

```
bot.on("edited.message", ctx => 
{
    console.log("edited")
});

bot.on("update", ctx => 
{
    console.log("edited")
});
```

but it doesn`t work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```js
bot.on('edited_message', (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.update.edited_message);
});
```

All availible types you can find in docs:
https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=update-types